# How to unpivot table with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to transpose a table called CHECK_CARD. It looks like this:

```
 _________________________________________________________________
|       anc_report_date       |  RiskSignal  | group_company_attr |
|_____________________________|______________|____________________|
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | NoRiskSignal |       4894543      |
| 2016-07-01 00:00:00.0000000 |  RiskSignal  |       1242151      |
```

I want it to look like this:

```
 ____________________________________________________________________________
|   anc_report_date  |2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000|2016-07-01 00:00:00.0000000|
|____________________|___________________________|___________________________|
| RiskSignal         |        NoRiskSignal       |        RiskSignal         |
| group_company_attr |          1242151          |          1242151          |
```

The number of rows in anc_report_date is dynamic so what I'm trying to do is:

```sql
DECLARE @Column NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Column
  = 'SELECT cc.anc_report_date
        from CHECK_CARD cc
        inner join CHECK_CARD chc on cc.group_company_attr=chc.group_company_attr and cc.anc_report_date<=chc.anc_report_date and chc.id=1832307
    where cc.status=1'
exec sp_executesql @Column
```

Here I collect all column names.

```sql
DECLARE @Column NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Column
  = 'SELECT cc.anc_report_date
        from CHECK_CARD cc
        inner join CHECK_CARD chc on cc.group_company_attr=chc.group_company_attr and cc.anc_report_date<=chc.anc_report_date and chc.id=1832307
    where cc.status=1'
DECLARE @Transpose as NVARCHAR(MAX)
set @Transpose
  = 'SELECT RiskSignal, group_company_attr
     from CHECK_CARD
     unpivot
     (
        kek
        for anc_report_date in ('+ @Column +')
     ) u'

exec sp_executesql @Transpose;
```

But when I use it all together it returns "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'."

I think this line `('+ @Columns +')` is the reason.

Any ideas?

```
     PRINT @Transpose;
[2019-09-19 18:54:42] [S0001] SELECT RiskSignal, group_company_attr
[2019-09-19 18:54:42] from CHECK_CARD
[2019-09-19 18:54:42] unpivot
[2019-09-19 18:54:42] (
[2019-09-19 18:54:42] kek
[2019-09-19 18:54:42] for anc_report_date in (SELECT cc.anc_report_date
[2019-09-19 18:54:42] from CHECK_CARD cc
[2019-09-19 18:54:42] inner join CHECK_CARD chc on cc.group_company_attr=chc.group_company_attr and cc.anc_report_date<=chc.anc_report_date and chc.id=1832307 where cc.status=1)
[2019-09-19 18:54:42] ) u
[2019-09-19 18:54:42] completed in 3 ms
```

Comment: This looks like you're mixing data types, which is a bad idea.

Comment: Did you try `PRINT @Transpose` before the EXEC, so you can look at the dynamic query to see if you can find the error?   If you did, and you still can't find the error, post the result so we can help.

Comment: Found out that I forgot "Select" in @Transpose, It didn't help.
PRINT @Transpose;
[S0001] SELECT RiskSignal, group_company_attr
from CHECK_CARD
unpivot
(
kek
for anc_report_date in (SELECT cc.anc_report_date
from CHECK_CARD cc
inner join CHECK_CARD chc on cc.group_company_attr=chc.group_company_attr and cc.anc_report_date<=chc.anc_report_date and chc.id=1832307 where cc.status=1)
) u
completed in 3 ms

Comment: `for anc_report_date in (SELECT cc.anc_report_date` cant do this in pivot/unpivot.. not sure any of your query is right

Comment: You can't just throw a query into the middle of a dynamic sql statement and expect it to run. You need to populate @Column with the result of that query, not the query you would use to generate the data. When you are working with dynamic sql you should ALWAYS print/select the dynamic sql you have generated to see if it is valid **before** you try running it.

Comment: `for anc_report_date in(` needs to be followed by a comma-separated list of a values.  Not a sub-select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it, Thanks all!

```sql
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(cc.id)
from CHECK_CARD cc
         inner join CHECK_CARD chc
                    on cc.group_company_attr = chc.group_company_attr and cc.anc_report_date <= chc.anc_report_date and
                       chc.id = 1832307
where cc.status = 1
      group by cc.id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT AttrName,' + @cols + N' from
(
  select id, AttrName, value
  from CHECK_CARD
  cross apply
  (
select ''RiskSignal'', cast(RiskSignalas varchar(50)) union all
select ''group_company_attr'', cast(group_company_attr varchar(50))
  ) c(AttrName, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for id in (' + @cols + N')
) piv';

exec sp_executesql @query;
```